# Function to find percentage of students enrolled in a subject - openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I'm new to OpenERP and I'm trying to make a function to find the percentage of students enrolled in a session. So far, the function compute_percentage is supposed to find the number of attendees per session.
The error I get is: AttributeError: 'Field attendee_id not found in browse_record(attendee.attendee, 3)'. What's missing in my code? Hope you can help, I've been at this for 3 whole days!

```
    class session(osv.osv):
    _name = 'session.session'  

    def compute_percentage(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
        record_id=ids[0]
        res={record_id:0.0}
        # percentage= (attendees/seats)*100
        current_form_object=self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        for r in current_form_object:
            other_form_object=self.pool.get("attendee.attendee").browse(cr,uid,ids)
            total= [item.attendee_id for item in other_form_object]
            res[item.id]=len(total)

        print res
        return res


    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Session Title', size = 50, required=True),
        'instructor_id':fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Instructor',ondelete="set null"),
        'start_date': fields.date('Start Date'),
        'duration': fields.integer('Duration'),
        'seats': fields.float('Number of Seats'),
        'attendee_ids':fields.one2many('attendee.attendee','attendee_id', 'Attendees'),
        'percentage':fields.function(compute_percentage, type='float', method=True, store=False, string='% of Headcount'),
        }

session()

class attendee(osv.osv):
    _name = 'attendee.attendee'   
    _columns = {
        'name':fields.char('Attendee Name'),
        'attendee_id':fields.many2one('res.partner','Attendee', ondelete="set null"),
        'session_id':fields.many2one('session.session', 'Session', ondelete="set null"),

        }

attendee()
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error? You may want to post the entire error message...

Comment: here you are browsing the table attendee.attendee with cursor in table session.session

Comment: The cursor is for the database, not for the table

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code for compute_percentage which may work if you do like this

```
def compute_percentage(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
        res = {}
        total =0.0
        for r in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            for line in r.attendee_ids:
                total+=1
            res[item.id]=total
        print res
        return res
```

For reference check sale.py _amount_all function